# unique Count of values in dimension using crossfilter (dc.js)

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I want to reduce the array below so that I can display it on NumberDisplay. Instead of displaying 2 its displaying 3 .  its not ignoring the duplicates in its calculations

```
[{
  "val": 28,
  "Title": "England"
}, {
  "val": 56,
  "Title": "USA"
}, {
  "val": 89,
  "Title": "England"
}]

  let dataDimension = xf.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.Title;
  });

  let dataGroup = dataDimension.group();
```

Comment: Usually the number display works with a groupAll, not an ordinary group. But this is one place where an ordinary group can be used nicely. I’ll vote to close as duplicate of a prior question, but feel free to comment if it doesn’t work for you.

Comment: @Gordon groupAll is giving me total number of all records but i am looking for unique counting of Titles

Comment: Yep that’s why I linked an answer which uses the count of groups! See the blue close banner.